# Inline editing of override image through XPM

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

I have to edit two Images through XPM but when I try do the editing I am not able to edit one Image. I am using the code written below in DWT.

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Component.Fields.Firstimagefield!=''" -->
  @@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.Firstimagefield")@@
    @@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
      <img src="@@GetMultiMediaLink('${ Component.Fields.Firstimagefield}')@@" tridion:type="Multimedia" title="@@GetEclMetadata('${ Component.Fields.Firstimagefield}','Description')@@" alt="@@GetEclMetadata('${ Component.Fields.Firstimagefield}','Description')@@" />
    @@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
  @@FieldEndMarker()@@
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->

@@FieldStartMarker("Component.Fields.Secondimagefield")@@
  @@FieldValueStartMarker()@@
    <img src="@@GetMultiMediaLink('${ Component.Fields.Secondimagefield}')@@" tridion:type="Multimedia" title="@@GetEclMetadata('${ Component.Fields.Secondimagefield}','Description')@@" alt="@@GetEclMetadata('${ Component.Fields.Secondimagefield}','Description')@@" class="intro-carousel-keyword"/>
  @@FieldValueEndMarker()@@
@@FieldEndMarker()@@
```

Comment: Can you check the source of the published page and show what HTML is actually generated, and add a snippet of that to the question (you can edit the question and add the HTML source formatted just like the DWT, so we all see if what was generated makes sense)?

Comment: I believe fields enabled for inline editing in XPM need a containing (HTML) element such as a `<div>`. If that's your complete DWT, consider trying adding a `<div>` around each image (starting before each `@@FieldStartMarker`).